# SQL Server : Relationships

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2019 for my project that is a Library management.

I was going to make a relationship from tblServices to tblCustomers that would get CustomerName from tblCustomer and set it into tblServices field CustomerName.
However when I was going to save the tables SQL Server prevent that and shown this error:

> Unable to create relationship 'FK_tblServices_tblCustomers'.
> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_tblServices_tblCustomers". The conflict occurred in database "Library_DB", table "dbo.tblCustomers", column 'CustomerName'.

I guess it tells I'm making a duplicate relationship on a same property. But I've checked it and it was just one relationship on CustomerName.

Comment: You should never use name as the foreign key field, you should use the primary key. You could easily have 2 customers with the same name.

Comment: No, it's telling you that while trying to add the foreign key constraint to `tblServices`, it found a `CustomerName` value that isn't in `tblCustomers`. It can't create a constraint enforcing all values are present when there is already a value that isn't. Are you really associating by _name_ (possible to change or have duplicates) vs. some surrogate ID?